# Looking for the correct TFS Environment variable.

Tags: tfs

I'm looking for the environment variable that holds the folder name that is created in the drop folder. But not the full path. only its name.

e.g.
Like its represented in Build definition->process->advanced->build number format.
after values have been populated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the name of the builddefinition? Can you give an example? Maybe this page will give some clues: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811617/where-is-the-droplocation-variable-in-tfs-build-2013

Comment: i'm looking for this:
build number format: 6.03.$(Date:MMdd)$(Rev:.r)
as populated environment variable.
e.g. 
the folder that the binaries are being compiled to is: 6.03.1701.1 this is what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the name of the build definition, check `TF_BUILD_BUILDDEFINITIONNAME`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh850448%28v=vs.120%29.aspx

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for. 
The comment above explains the value i'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Finally this is solved.
The environment variable that helped me to get this value is
**TF_BUILD_BUILDNUMBER**,
This is what i was looking for.

Regards.